# Running node with npm

Tags: node.js, npm

I need to run node with a different space size
like this

```
node --max_old_space_size=4096
```

but I need to combine it with the following command for npm

```
npm run build:aot:prod
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new script in package.json like this:

`"myscript": "npm run build:aot:prod && node --max_old_space_size=4096 mynodefile.js"`

You can then run it by `npm run myscript`.

Comment: Thanks I will try this. Why do I need the mynodefile.js ?

Comment: Usually because you use node to launch a node script, i added it just for completness. If you know its not needed dont use it